# auto update calculations derived from pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, pivot-table

I have looked around at other posts and found what I thought was my same issue though the resolution does not work. I have a pivot table of data that I use pull percentages into certain cells. I am using `Hlookup` to identify the name in the column header then return two values from the appropriate row of the column for my formula. Everything returns the values exactly how I want them, however I noticed that when I refresh the data in my pivot table, the values driven by formulas do not update, only when I re-enter the cell and press enter, or click the calculate sheet button.

A previous post that I saw mentioned using `getpivotdata` which I also tried but with the same result, the formula driven values do not auto update.

Any suggestions? I am wondering if I should add a macro that just recalculates the sheet or book once the pivot table is refreshed.

thanks a ton.

Comment: Is your workbook set to Automatic under Formulas > Calculation Options?

Comment: Yes that was one of the first suggestions in some of the posts I read. I'm not sure what it was but it's corrected itself after uploading a newer version on SharePoint.

Not sure if I should mark this as answered or what

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cells not updating automatically](http://superuser.com/questions/836324/cells-not-updating-automatically)